# Does "enclosed" in Luke 5:6 help us understand "consigned" in Romans 11:32?

Tags: word-study, romans

> "For God has consigned all to disobedience, that he may have mercy on all". Romans 11:32 ESV [consigned/synekleisen].

> "And when they had done this, they enclosed a large number of fish, and their nets were breaking". Luke 5:6 ESV. [enclosed/synekleisan].

Perhaps in Luke 5:6 the fish were enclosed in the net not just because it was there, but because their God given natures caused them to swim into it, or near it.

Does the Luke 5:6 use of the word enclosed/synekleisen help us to understand how God consigned all to disobedience in Romans  11:32, or does it just tell us that he did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative verb here is συγκλείω (sugkleió), which, according to BDAG means:

1. **to catch by enclosing, *close up together, hem in, enclose***, eg, Luke 5:6
2. **to confine to specific limits, *confine, imprison***, eg, Rom 11:32, Gal 3:22, 23

Several versions reflect this accurately in Rom 11:32:

- NIV, BSB, BLB, : bound
- NLT, CSB: imprisoned
- NASB: shut up

... and so forth.  Thus, Rom 11:32, simply states a fact but not the mechanism, ie, it does not say how this was done.